# Coloring $\mathbb{N}$ such that $\{a, b, a+b\}$ is not monochromatic

Tags: co.combinatorics, infinite-combinatorics

Let $\mathbb{N}:=\omega \setminus \{0\}$. Is there $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and a map $c:\mathbb{N}\to \{1,\ldots,k\}$ such that for all $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$ the restriction $c|_{\{a,\,b,\,a+b\}}$ is non-constant?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, this is the content of [Schur's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_theorem).